# Update to change only the left side of a field value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that contains a (virtual) path to a file. In the path field you might see data such as:

```
path
====
folder1
folder2
folder1/111
folder1/111/abc
folder1/111/abc/xyz
folder1/222
```

If the user wants to move the folder '111' (located in folder 1) to folder 2, then it should move both itself and any nested folders (abc and xyz). So, the results I would expect to see are as follows:

```
path
====
folder1
folder2
folder2/111
folder2/111/abc
folder2/111/abc/xyz
folder1/222
```

I have not been able to come up with a way to indicate specifically the left side of a string with the REPLACE() function, but did come up with this:

```
update table set path = replace(path, 'folder1/', 'folder2/')
where path like 'folder1/111/%';
```

The percent symbol being only on the right hand side would only modify the rows that start with 'folder1/111/'. However, the one concern I have with this is if a path was like this:

```
folder1/111/folder1/abc
```

Then the replace function would end up replacing both folder1 instances with folder2.

Note: I will be using PHP to create the mysql query so have thought about using the LEFT() function as well. However, I feel I am still missing something with that approach.

How can I do this search and replace effectively by replacing only text as it appears on the left side of the field?

**Update**

Based on one of the answers below, I have come up with something close:

```
update Test as t,
    (select insert(path, locate('folder1', path), char_length('folder1'), 'folder2') as path from Test) as ins
     set t.path = ins.path
     where LEFT(t.path, 10) = 'folder1/111';
```

See my [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15e55c/1).

My issue, however, is that is replacing the entire path with 'folder2' not just a portion of the path.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `LEFT()` is not giving you the result, You can try the other String functions to get the same result.

```
select path,INSERT(path, LOCATE('folder1', path), CHAR_LENGTH('folder1'), 'folder2')
from yourtable;
```

I have given the `select` query. You can use your `update` accordingly.

Fiddle: [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a91e2/3)

Reference of the docs: [LOCATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_locate), [INSERT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_insert), [CHAR_LENGTH()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length)

**To `UPDATE`**

```
update Test set path = INSERT(path, LOCATE('folder1', path), CHAR_LENGTH('folder1'), 'folder2')
where path like 'folder1/111/%';
```

Fiddle : [For Update](https://paiza.io/projects/ykPaccvj_agfNno6BvXUlQ?language=mysql)

Comment: I have updated my question with your advice, however, it seems to be replacing the whole field, rather than just a portion of it.

Comment: Thank you, the only issue I had was that it did not work to move folders to or from the root directory. I think refactoring how paths are stored in the database with always using a trailing slash fixes this. I'll just need to figure out how to refactor my PHP code as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The reference guides you provides were quite useful as well as the other site you posted to compensate for sqlfiddle being down.

Comment: Welcome :). Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

```
update table path = replace(path, 'folder1', 'folder2') 
where path like 'folder1/111%'
```

Comment: This will still replace multiple occurrences of folder1 if they appear on the same line.